# transfer some informations from one database to another with php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql database called A.

I would like to to get informations where country=usa (There are about 40 000 with usa) and i want to insert to B database.

How i can do that with php?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you show us your current, non-working code we can help you fix it. If you are looking for handouts or tutorials, you'd be better off elsewhere because this is not the place for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this slowly with PHP:

```
<?php
$data = mysql_query("SELECT x,y,z FROM db1.table WHERE where country='usa'");
$values = Array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data)) {
    // do some work...
    $row['x'] = mysql_real_escape_string($row['x']);
    $row['y'] = mysql_real_escape_string($row['y']);
    $row['z'] = mysql_real_escape_string($row['z']);
    $values[] = "('$row[x]','$row[y]','$row[z]')";
}
mysql_query("insert into db2.table (x,y,z) VALUES ".implode(',',$values)."");
?>
```

But i prefer quicker and simplier MySQL INSERT ... SELECT statement, directly in MySQL console:

```
INSERT INTO db2.table (x,y,z) SELECT x,y,z FROM db1.table WHERE country='usa';
```

Comment: Your mysql console solution is great but how to choose all the row?

Comment: @samim basar: INSERT INTO db2.table SELECT * FROM db1.table WHERE country='usa';

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM database1.table_name WHERE country = 'USA'";
    $result2 = mysql_query($query);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    //assigning of value to variable
    $val1 = $row['field_name1'];
    $val2 = $row['filed_name2'];
    //and so on

    $query2 = "INSERT INTO database2.table_name (field1,field2,.....) VALUES ('$val1', 'val2',....)"
    $result2 = mysql_query($query2);
    }


?>
```

Comment: He's asking about different databases, not tables. And I know it's none of my business and that you're new here, but please don't spoon feed those who don't care to put even the bare-minimum effort before asking.

Comment: @Madmartigan : I'm sorry, I can edit my solution but first I want to thank you for your advice, your right maybe he should put an effort by solving first the problem before asking here. ;)

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Sorry for disturbing your

Comment: @MārisKiseļovs: Thanks for noticing that. Though I prefer your answer more.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do a dump of the database schema and data, as a big SQL file, and just run that SQL on the different database... no need for PHP scripting at all if you have phpMyAdmin.  Just use the operations tab on the main database screen.  Export database on the source, import it in to the destination.